# How to retrieve Keycloak client roles in Spring Security

Tags: java, jwt, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing a Spring boot application which authenticates with Keycloak. I want to protect my REST endpoints, all are matching "/api/**". The rest is permitAll.
I can easily authorize requests by the below code snippet, but it only works with Keycloak's **realm** role, it does not work with **client** role.

```
private void configureMyRole(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("MyClientRole")
    .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Both the realm and client roles are available in the JWT token, but how should I handle it in Java? How can I retrieve it?

```js
{
    "jti": "ae1043ca-db2b-4cbd-88dd-d6a7017db92f",
    "exp": 1633563788,
    "rest": "omitted",
    "realm_access": {
        "roles": [
            "MyRealmRole",
            "offline_access",
            "uma_authorization"
        ]
    },
    "resource_access": {
        "myproject": {
            "roles": [
                "MyClientRole"
            ]
        },
        "account": {
            "roles": [
                "manage-account",
                "manage-account-links",
                "view-profile"
            ]
        }
    },
    "rest": "omitted"
}
```

I am sure I could come up with some home made approach, parsing the token myself in some filter, but I better not ... :D

Answer (score 0):

Just recently i got the same issue, I've tried to convert it to an **ObjectNode** directly but, it seems that **Claims** can only be converted to a **LinkedHashMap** using **Jackson**.
In my case I needed to get a **String[]** of roles to be used later within my **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(publicKey)
        .parseClaimsJws(token)
        .getBody();

ObjectNode y = mapper.convertValue(mapper.convertValue(claims.get("resource_access")
        , LinkedHashMap.class)
        , ObjectNode.class);

return StreamSupport.stream(y.get("myproject").get("roles").spliterator(), false)
        .map(JsonNode::asText)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```